# What does 收 mean in 他把何进部下的兵都收归己有?

Tags: meaning

This is from near the  beginning of 三国演义 and I am already puzzled：

他把何进部下的兵都收归己有。 Maybe: He （收？) recaptured / imprisoned all the troops under 何进's command

归己有： returned them to his own command ??

收 is '收复‘ or '收监‘ or some other word？

Comment: That's wrong, "收" in "收歸" means "take"; "歸" in "收歸" means "assign to"  or "allocate  to" . As in "收歸國有",  which means: "Take possession (of a company) and assign it to become State-owned " - The country didn't own this company before, so it can't be called "regain", "retake" or "take back"

Answer (score 3):

> 收 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/687/
>
> [3] [v] receive; accept; **take**

~

> 歸 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2343/
>
> [3] **belong to**; rest with; be in charge

己= self

有= possession

收歸己有 = "take possession and make it belong to oneself"

There's a common phrase "收歸國有", which means "Take possession (of a company) and assign it to become State-owned " . Similarly "收歸己有" in your sentence would mean : ""Take possession (of an army) and assign it to become Self-owned "